# Solve the following system of equations (1)

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

> Solve the following system of equations:
>   $$\large
> \left \{
> \begin{aligned}
> \sqrt{x + 2}(x - y + 3) &= \sqrt{y}\\
> x^2 + (x + 3)(2x - y + 5) &= x + 16
> \end{aligned}
> \right.$$

That is definitely not easy to solve for me.
I try to solve the question by letting $x + 2 = a$ and $x - y + 3 = b$ but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt{x+2}$ and $b=\sqrt{y}$, then first equation is $$a^3+a-ab^2=b$$ so $$ a(a-b)(a+b)+a-b=0$$
and thus $$(a-b)(a^2+ab+1)=0$$

Case 1: $a=b$ so $y=x+2$:...

Case 2: $a^2+ab =-1$ is impossible since $a,b\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Squaring the first equation and factorizing we get
$$(x-y+2)(x^2-xy+6x-2y+9)=0$$ so we get
$$x-y+2=0$$
or
$$x^2-xy+6x-2y+9=0$$
Can you proceed now?

Comment: Where is the other system?